# How to express complex iOS screen layouts

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, interface-builder

I am trying to implement a fairly complex screen layout on an iOS 7 app (which I know will run on iPhone only).

The screen layout is quite dynamic in nature and looks like this:

```
+----------------------------+
|                            |
| hero image, 320px x 150 px |
|                            |
+----------------------------+
|    full width button       |
+----------------------------+
|  timestamp (one line)      |
|  LARGE CAPTION (one line)  |
|                            |
|  Intro text       +--------+
|  that may take up |Image   |
|  a few lines, but |aligned |
|  don't actually   |to intro|
|  know for sure how|text    |
|  many             +--------+
+----------------------------+
|  Some    Data              |
|  In      Tabular           |
|  Form    Which may go over |
|          more than one line|
+------------HR--------------+
|  Long piece of text,       |
|  several paragraphs,       |
|  must scroll for as long   |
|  as needed.                |
+----------------------------+
|  Some footer text          |
+----------------------------+
```

The whole screen will definitely need to scroll.

The usual approaches I have found for this are:

**UITableView**

Each component is a row within a UITableView -- the problem being that we don't know in advance the height of each row, so manual text calculations are required.

**UIScrollView/AutoLayout**

Never used this to any huge extent, but I can't figure out how to create a lengthy list of components using Interface Builder -- it all takes up more than one screen in the UIScrollView.

Most approaches also need quite a lot of code to be written to calculate heights, and also to specify widget fonts, colours and heights.

I already know a versatile language for expressing the heights, alignments and relationships between all these components: CSS.  I would be tempted to use a webview for the whole thing but: this is not the style of the rest of the project, and also, interactive components such as buttons must behave as native.

What's the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: If you are going to use IB, this should be simple. You would want to definitely use UIScrollView, but I am not sure about AutoLayout. UITableView will not make your screen look as you described. Are you using XCode/IB?

Comment: Yes.  But UIScrollView needs to know the x/y positions of all components within it, does it not?  How can this work for a component coming below a piece of text whose height you don't know?

Comment: Hi, I just wanted to follow up and see if the below answer worked for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can all be done in Interfacebuilder using Auto Layout which is available in iOS7 which you are using.

This is basic functionality which is discussed at: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

An example of creating one such connections follows:

[image]

For your picture, just add an extra "line" on top of intro text which functions as a guide for the Intro text and the image. The line will not be visible.

Since this is a mostly vertical application you will be able to simple connect the lower edge of one element to the upper edge of the lower element.

Also, you will benefit by being able to use iOS7 font capabilities which will automatically layout your UI based on font size changes. These preferences can also be set by the user for accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

> **UITableView**
>
> Each component is a row within a UITableView -- the problem being that
>   we don't know in advance the height of each row, so manual text
>   calculations are required.

So what's the problem with that? If your rows aren't all the same height, the table view will ask its data source for the height of each row as it needs it. This isn't a good option if you plan to have a thousand rows, but that's not the case here. You've only got five or six rows, so variable row heights isn't a problem.

Because each row in your layout has a different appearance, you're going to want to provide a number of different cell types. It's easy to lay these out in IB, so it shouldn't be a problem.

> **UIScrollView/AutoLayout**
>
> Never used this to any huge extent, but I can't figure out how to
>   create a lengthy list of components using Interface Builder

It's pretty straightforward -- you arrange your views inside a container view, and set up constraints such that the top of one view is constrained to the bottom of the previous view. Since you're going to adjust the height of each subview at runtime you don't need to include the full height of each subview in the storyboard. Use a shortened version to make it easy to arrange them in IB.

Comment: "So what's the problem with [manual text calculations]"?  It's more code to write now, and remember to change later.  Why can't I just stack items one on top of the other, like LinearLayout in Android, or StackPanel on WindowsPhone?

Comment: @funkybro You *can* – that's exactly what autolayout does for you.

Comment: So why using AutoLayout do I need to "adjust the height of each subview at runtime"?  And won't the UIScrollView need to know the full height of all its contents?

Comment: @funkybro Perhaps I misunderstood, but it sounded like the height of several of your views were of variable height. If that's not the case, then you don't have to adjust anything. On the other hand, if the rows  mostly have fixed height, then calculating the height for variable row heights in a table is also very straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a library for this purpose. I don't know why Apple doesn't provide that for default, it's insane. [ETFlowView](https://github.com/trilhagroup/ETFlowView), it's available on Github.